# Vue CLI 5 - Can I extract a send CSS file (and only CSS file) for a dark mode theme and then also inject it into my HTML?

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, bulma, darkmode

I'm building a Vue (2) app with Vue CLI 5 in conjunction with the Bulma CSS from work via their SCSS repo and would. would like to generate 2 separate CSS files, one for light mode and one for dark mode.

My plan would be to have 2 sets of variable files, 1 set for light mode and one for dark mode. Then I would ideally build out 2 different css files, light-mode.css and dark-mode.css

So how can I:

- Generate 2 the separate CSS files
- Can I have both files injected into my HTML? (if I cant I would use JS to add it later)

Answer (score 0):

Why two separate files ?

Could not make just one file and use css variables (`var`) ?

Like this:

```
:root {
    --default-background-color: #fff;
    --default-color: #000;
    /*
    other variables for theme - default light
     */
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --default-background-color: #000;
        --default-color: #aaa;
        /*
        other variables for theme
         */

    }
}
body {
    background-color: var(--default-background-color);
    color: var(--default-color);
    /*
    common style inherited by both themes, dar and light
     */
}

......
```